# p-value of two side alternative

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, p-value

In the hypotehses testing, I would like to see an intuition how the operator $\min$ and the constant $2$ in the computation of $p$-value of a two side alternative $p = 2\min(F(T_0), 1-F(T_0))$ can
be derived and understood for a statistics $T_0$. Here $F$ is the c.d.f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$-value is used to assess how likely we shall get an outcome extremer than the current statistic. Let the parameter to be estimated by $\theta$. Here, since we are given with a two-sided alternative, we can take $p$-value to be the probability for statistic $T$ such that $$|T-\theta|\geq|T_0-\theta|.$$ For one-sided alternative, the absolute value is not needed.

Now consider an ideal case: the normal curve, and assume, WLOG, that $T_0>\theta$ locates at the right of the mean. Then the probability for getting values even *greater* than $T_0$ is $1-F(T_0)$. For the symmetric cdf, the $p$-value here is $$2\cdot(1-F(T_0)).$$

Likewise, if $T_0<\theta$, then the probability of getting a *smaller* value is $F(T_0)$, so the $p$-value can be assigned with $$2\cdot F(T_0).$$

Note that in the first case $1-F(T_0)<0.5<F(T_0)$ and in the second case $F(T_0)<0.5<1-F(T_0)$, so we shall use the minimum operator when we want to combine them in one formula.

Comment: How have you obtained 2 in your "the $p$-value is "$$2\cdot(1-F(T_0))$$ ?

Comment: It is because of symmetry. Let $\mu$ be the mean. Here $1-F(T_0)=P(T-\mu>T_0-\mu)$. For $P(|T-\mu|>T_0-\mu)$, you have to multiply it by $2$. Remember we are taking two-sided alternative here. If it is one-sided, we do not need to multiply it by $2$.

Comment: I'm perhaps too focused on detail, but does it make a difference whether you write $P(|T-\mu|>T_0-\mu)$ or $P(|T-\mu|>|T_0-\mu|)$ ?

Comment: Sorry for bringing you confusion. It should be $|T_0-\mu|$ but I can't correct it now.

Comment: But about your $|T-\theta|>|T_0-\theta|$: I have never seen this formula. I've always seen this form $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ and $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$. How these two are related ?

Comment: Frankly speaking, the formula $|T-\theta|>|T_0-\theta|$ is an example for illustrating the idea of $p$-value, that it measures the probability of obtaining extremer observations than current one, since you only asked for the intuition behind it. It has nothing to do with specific setups of hypotheses.

Comment: I'm struggling hard with the fact in your last sentence in the answer. I really do not follow why using $\min$ does the job from the fact that $1-T_0$ follows $F_0$ and in second equation on the contrary.How now application $\min$ works well ? There are 4 places where they occur. I'd like to understand this in detail. So why 2$\min(F(T_0),1-F(T_0))$ is the right thing ?